# PGFPLOTS How to increase the line width without increasing the marker border width

Tags: pgfplots

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
            enlarge x limits=0.1,
            enlarge y limits=0.1,
            ]
        \addplot [
            mark=*,
            color=blue,
            scatter,
            scatter/use mapped color={draw=black},
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir = both, 
            y explicit,
            error bar style={color=black},
            ] table [x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{
            0 2 0.1
            2 0 0.1
            };
        \addplot [line width=2pt,
            mark=*,
            color=red,
            scatter,
            scatter/use mapped color={draw=black},
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir = both, 
            y explicit,
            error bar style={color=black},
            ] table [x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{
            0 0 0.1
            2 2 0.1
            };
            
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

How do I increase the line width while leaving the marker border width intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the purpose of `mark options` to control the parameters of the marks. So by dialing `mark options={line width=0.4pt}` you can set the line width to its standard value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
            enlarge x limits=0.1,
            enlarge y limits=0.1,
            ]
        \addplot [
            mark=*,
            color=blue,
            scatter,
            scatter/use mapped color={draw=black},
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir = both, 
            y explicit,
            error bar style={color=black},
            ] table [x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{
            0 2 0.1
            2 0 0.1
            };
        \addplot [line width=2pt,mark options={line width=0.4pt},
            mark=*,
            color=red,
            scatter,
            scatter/use mapped color={draw=black},
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir = both, 
            y explicit,
            error bar style={color=black},
            ] table [x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{
            0 0 0.1
            2 2 0.1
            };
            
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]